# Split date into YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS and aggregate date (R)

Tags: r, date, datetime, split, aggregate

How can one split the following `datetime` into `year-month-day-hour-minute-second`? The date was created using:

```
datetime = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2015-04-01 0:00:00", tz = 'GMT'), 
                                           as.POSIXct("2015-11-30 23:59:59", tz = 'GMT'), 
                                           by="hour",tz="GMT"))
```

The ultimate goal is to aggregate `x` which is at `hourly` resolution into `6-hourly` resolution. Probably it is possible to `aggregate datetime` without needing to split it?

```
             datetime     x 
1  2015-04-01 00:00:00    0.0     
2  2015-04-01 01:00:00    0.0     
3  2015-04-01 02:00:00    0.0     
4  2015-04-01 03:00:00    0.0     
5  2015-04-01 04:00:00    0.0     
6  2015-04-01 05:00:00    0.0     
7  2015-04-01 06:00:00    0.0     
8  2015-04-01 07:00:00    0.0     
9  2015-04-01 08:00:00    0.0     
10 2015-04-01 09:00:00    0.0     
11 2015-04-01 10:00:00    0.0     
12 2015-04-01 11:00:00    0.0     
13 2015-04-01 12:00:00    0.0     
14 2015-04-01 13:00:00    0.0     
15 2015-04-01 14:00:00    0.0     
16 2015-04-01 15:00:00    0.0     
17 2015-04-01 16:00:00    0.0     
18 2015-04-01 17:00:00    0.0     
19 2015-04-01 18:00:00    0.0     
20 2015-04-01 19:00:00    0.0     
21 2015-04-01 20:00:00    0.0     
22 2015-04-01 21:00:00    0.0     
23 2015-04-01 22:00:00    1.6     
24 2015-04-01 23:00:00    0.2     
25 2015-04-02 00:00:00    1.5     
26 2015-04-02 01:00:00    1.5     
27 2015-04-02 02:00:00    0.5     
28 2015-04-02 03:00:00    0.0     
29 2015-04-02 04:00:00    0.0     
30 2015-04-02 05:00:00    0.0     
31 2015-04-02 06:00:00    0.0     
32 2015-04-02 07:00:00    0.5     
33 2015-04-02 08:00:00    0.3     
34 2015-04-02 09:00:00    0.0     
35 2015-04-02 10:00:00    0.0     
36 2015-04-02 11:00:00    0.0     
37 2015-04-02 12:00:00    0.0     
38 2015-04-02 13:00:00    0.0     
39 2015-04-02 14:00:00    0.0     
40 2015-04-02 15:00:00    0.0     
41 2015-04-02 16:00:00    0.0     
42 2015-04-02 17:00:00    0.0     
43 2015-04-02 18:00:00    0.0     
44 2015-04-02 19:00:00    0.0     
45 2015-04-02 20:00:00    0.0     
46 2015-04-02 21:00:00    0.0     
47 2015-04-02 22:00:00    0.0     
48 2015-04-02 23:00:00    0.0 
....
```

The output should be very close to:

```
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss  YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss  YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss  YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
2015-04-01 00:00:00  2015-04-01 06:00:00  2015-04-01 12:00:00  2015-04-01 18:00:00
2015-04-02 00:00:00  2015-04-02 06:00:00  2015-04-02 12:00:00  2015-04-02 18:00:00 
.....
```

I appreciate your thoughts on this.

**EDIT**

How to implement @r2evans answer on a list object such as:

```
 x = runif(5856)
    flst1=list(x,x,x,x)

    flst1=lapply(flst1, function(x){x$datetime <- as.POSIXct(x$datetime, tz = "GMT"); x})

    sixhours1=lapply(flst1, function(x) {x$bin <- cut(x$datetime,sixhours);x})

    head(sixhours1[[1]],n=7)

    ret=lapply(sixhours1, function(x) aggregate(x$precip, list(x$bin), sum,na.rm=T))

    head(ret[[1]],n=20)
```

Comment: Study the vignette(s) of the zoo package. It's all there.

Comment: Perhaps you can use another `seq` (with `by="6 hours"`) and `cut`?

Comment: @r2evans       how can I implement your idea using the data provided above? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your minimal data is incomplete, so I'll generate something random:

```
dat <- data.frame(datetime = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2015-04-01 0:00:00", tz = "GMT"),
                                        as.POSIXct("2015-11-30 23:59:59", tz = "GMT"), 
                                        by = "hour",tz = "GMT"),
                  x = runif(5856))
# the "1+" ensures we extend at least to the end of the datetimes;
# without it, the last several rows in "bin" would be NA
sixhours <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2015-04-01 0:00:00", tz = "GMT"),
                       1 + as.POSIXct("2015-11-30 23:59:59", tz = "GMT"), 
                       by = "6 hours",tz = "GMT")

# this doesn't have to go into the data.frame (could be a separate
# vector), but I'm including it for easy row-wise comparison
dat$bin <- cut(dat$datetime, sixhours)

head(dat, n=7)
#              datetime          x                 bin
# 1 2015-04-01 00:00:00 0.91022534 2015-04-01 00:00:00
# 2 2015-04-01 01:00:00 0.02638850 2015-04-01 00:00:00
# 3 2015-04-01 02:00:00 0.42486354 2015-04-01 00:00:00
# 4 2015-04-01 03:00:00 0.90722845 2015-04-01 00:00:00
# 5 2015-04-01 04:00:00 0.24540085 2015-04-01 00:00:00
# 6 2015-04-01 05:00:00 0.60360906 2015-04-01 00:00:00
# 7 2015-04-01 06:00:00 0.01843313 2015-04-01 06:00:00
tail(dat)
#                 datetime         x                 bin
# 5851 2015-11-30 18:00:00 0.5963204 2015-11-30 18:00:00
# 5852 2015-11-30 19:00:00 0.2503440 2015-11-30 18:00:00
# 5853 2015-11-30 20:00:00 0.9600476 2015-11-30 18:00:00
# 5854 2015-11-30 21:00:00 0.6837394 2015-11-30 18:00:00
# 5855 2015-11-30 22:00:00 0.9093506 2015-11-30 18:00:00
# 5856 2015-11-30 23:00:00 0.9197769 2015-11-30 18:00:00
nrow(dat)
# [1] 5856
```

The work:

```
ret <- aggregate(dat$x, list(dat$bin), mean)
nrow(ret)
# [1] 976
head(ret)
#               Group.1         x
# 1 2015-04-01 00:00:00 0.5196193
# 2 2015-04-01 06:00:00 0.4770019
# 3 2015-04-01 12:00:00 0.5359483
# 4 2015-04-01 18:00:00 0.8140603
# 5 2015-04-02 00:00:00 0.4874332
# 6 2015-04-02 06:00:00 0.6139554
tail(ret)
#                 Group.1         x
# 971 2015-11-29 12:00:00 0.6881228
# 972 2015-11-29 18:00:00 0.4791925
# 973 2015-11-30 00:00:00 0.5793872
# 974 2015-11-30 06:00:00 0.4809868
# 975 2015-11-30 12:00:00 0.5157432
# 976 2015-11-30 18:00:00 0.7199298
```

Comment: OH wow! @r2evans let me compare your solution with mine provided below. Your dates are well ordered as expected

Comment: why is `pp=aggregate(dat10$x, list(dat10$bin), sum)`;
> nrow(pp) = `975 instead of 976`? `5856/6` =`976`. In my case below: `nrow(stations6hrly[[703]])
[1] 976`. All other data sets against which this will be compared have 976 rows as well.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I wanted. The values align with timestamp unlike those in my solution below. I will now learn how to write your code for use on a `list` object

Comment: Can you please write these lines in list format? `dat$bin <- cut(dat$datetime, sixhours)` and `ret <- aggregate(dat$x, list(dat$bin), mean)`. `sixhours=lapply(sixhours, function(x) {x$bin <- cut(x$datetime, x); x})` gives an error:  `Error in cut(x$datetime, x) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'cut': Error in x$datetime : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors `

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. If it's straight-forward, edit your question, don't post lost of code and error in a comment.

Comment: I was asking how to use your solution on a `list object`

Comment: You provided a `data.frame` and I answered for a `data.frame`. If you have data structured in a `list` (versus a vector), please provide a sample of it. I don't have time to guess your format.

Comment: I suggest you read something like @hadley's [R Data Structures](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html), specifically the sections on "*Vectors"* (and Lists) and "*Data frames*". You are mistaking the first two and not understanding that a column of a `data.frame` is (usually) just a vector. `cut` takes a minimum of two arguments, both of which are vectors, so my answer is actually working on vectors (that happen to be vectors in a `data.frame`).

Comment: Thanks@r2evans. See my edit above for my take on applying the solution to list object.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution using:

```
library(xts)
flst<- list.files(pattern=".csv")
flst1<- lapply(flst,function(x) read.csv(x,header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,sep = ",",fill=TRUE, 
                                        dec = ".",quote = "\"",colClasses=c('factor', 'numeric', 'NULL'))) # read files ignoring 3 column
head(flst1[[1]])
dat.xts=lapply(flst1, function(x) xts(x$precip,as.POSIXct(x$datetime)))
head(dat.xts[[1]])
ep.xts=lapply(dat.xts, function(x) endpoints(x, on="hours", k=6))#k=by .... see endpoints for "on"
head(ep.xts[[1]])
stations6hrly<-lapply(dat.xts, function(x) period.apply(x, FUN=sum,INDEX=ep))

head(stations6hrly[[703]])
                    [,1]
2015-04-01 05:00:00  0.3
2015-04-01 11:00:00  1.2
2015-04-01 17:00:00  0.0
2015-04-01 23:00:00  0.2
2015-04-02 05:00:00  0.0
2015-04-02 11:00:00  1.4
```

The dates are not as I wanted them to be but the values are correct. I doubt if there is a `-shifttime` function in R just as in `CDO`